# Create common modules between projects [COCOS2D]

Tags: javascript, node.js, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

Hello I want to make some projects(games) with cocos2d(im new into this) that will take code or maybe some assets from a common folder. how can i achieve that? for example i write a generic module that will have a state machine manager and i want to use it on both of my two cocos projects. Thank you in advance! (im using cocos creator)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it here is how I did it if anyone have the same problem. i putted all my cocos project into one folder and I made in that project a folder name common_assets. after that I did go on every project assets folder and did that on powershell as an admin:
ni -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path common_assets -Target ....\common_assets
That will make a symbolicLink somehow different from a normal windows on that will do the job on all of your project that have it. if you make change on common from an project it goes on any project!